# How to integrate a c/c++ library into objective c

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, c

A company has asked me to deliver them a c/c++ library. They want to use it in an iphone app, which is objective c based.

I would prefer to deliver a library as opposed to code.

Could they wrap the c/c++ library into their iphone app without any need to see the source code?

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean static libraries ?

Comment: Hi Maulik. Yes, I guess it will have to be a static library. I know very little about iphone development and xcode. Can you use a shared library in this environment in the same way you would use a .so, .dll or .dylib in linux/win/Mac ? thanks

Comment: You cannot dynamically load a library in iOS. You can use a static library however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand you want to deliver a binary file for them to use in the application. If that is true then Yes it is possible but there is a catch you need to compile the library using the x code compiler for C++, and make sure that anything you use in your library is compatible whit the compiler.(make sure the library is compatible with armv7 and armv7s architectures). And as for the wrapper, there is no need for wrappers , they can use directly the c++ syntax inside code in .mm files. but if it's a must then they can use a wrapper generator to build the wrapper.

Comment: Hi Radu, thanks for your answer. OK, so the process is: 1- In XCode, to create a static library project
2- To add all the c/c++ code to the project (.cpp and .h)
3- Compile using xcode compiler to ensure armv7 and armv7s compatibility. is this correct?

Comment: there are serval ways of doing it, i prefer to compile using Terminal commands and write the makefiles for the compiler, but you are correct using in the above method it works the same. here is a tutorial about it http://neilmonday.blogspot.ro/2008/02/how-to-compile-basic-c-programs-in.html

Comment: "make sure the library is compatible with armv7 and armv7s architectures" - nowadays it should be compatible with arm64 also

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer below links to create Static library : links shows step by step process

1. http://www.lextech.com/2013/02/static-libraries-in-ios/
2. http://jaym2503.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-make-universal-static-library.html